# Using Angular Service to provide data into different component

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-services

My intention is to send data from one component to another. The user can choose between 3 different offers - the click events provide different data (in this case numbers from 1 to 3) - these data is saved in the Sender as "selectedDiv" - (*following isn't working*) data from "selectedDiv" shall be send to Reciever and **is also to be updated when "selectedDiv" in the sending component changes**.

I've already found suggestions on stackoverflow.com, but none of them worked out for me.

Summarized:
The component which is supposed to send data contains a number which is to be forwarded to a different component.

My progress so far:

**Service:**

```
export class SelectedService {
  selectedDiv: number;

  changeNumber(div: number) {
    this.selectedDiv = div;
  }
}
```

**Sender:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {SelectedService} from '../selected.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-wedding',
  templateUrl: './wedding.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./wedding.component.css'],
  providers: [SelectedService]
})
export class WeddingComponent implements OnInit {

  selectedDiv: number;

  public onChoose(event): void {
    this.selectedDiv = event;
    this.selectedService.changeNumber(this.selectedDiv);

  }

  constructor(private selectedService: SelectedService) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

**Reciever:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {SelectedService} from '../selected.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-contact',
  templateUrl: './contact.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./contact.component.css'],
  providers: [SelectedService]
})
export class ContactComponent implements OnInit {

  selectedDiv: number;

  constructor(private selectedService: SelectedService) {
    this.selectedDiv = this.selectedService.selectedDiv;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Edit:
The first approach showed following error: *this.selectedService.changeNumber is not a function*

**Screenshot from Augury (receiving component somehow remains empty):**

Sending WeddingComponent:
[WeddingComponent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJosd.png)

Receiving ContactComponent:
[ContactComponent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1S7gx.png)

Comment: Do you have any error in console ?

Comment: @mJehanno Yes: this.selectedService.changeNumber is not a function, should've checked this before

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you are providing the `SelectedService` directly in the components, therefore you are getting two different instances of the same class.

You have 3 solutions:

- Register the provider in a component parent of both `WeddingComponent` and `ContactComponent`
- Register the provider in the module containing both `WeddingComponent` and `ContactComponent`
- Add `provideIn: root` as a parameter of the `Injectable` decorator directly in the service

Depending on the scope of the service you need to choose one option.

Comment: Thank you. I've tried to solve it with the Injectable decorator, which I think kind of helped - the console stopped showing the mentioned error and Augury started to show the number inside of the SelectedService object in the providing WeddingComponent. However, looking at the receiving ContactComponent, the SelectedService's object remains empty.

Comment: I've added some screenshots of Augury in my initial question.

Comment: Did you remove the `providers: [SelectedService]` line on both components? Seems like you're still having different instances of the service.